# Can we enforce named imports in Python (and 'disable' * imports)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python allows for importing symbols from other modules using the `import <symbol>` statement. Similarly, I can also say `from <module> import *` and it will import all the symbols from `module.py`.

Now, say if I want to not allow anyone to import `*` from my module, can I override this functionality and disable it? I.e. can I enforce that users of my module can only import symbols by their names and not the `*` wildcard; say, if you import using `*` wildcard, the Python interpreter would throw an error.

I know that most Python linters would catch and flag such imports by default (or if configured); but I was wondering if there's a way I can enforce such a thing in my module code itself.

Comment: Do you require an error to be thrown, or are you fine with otherwise restricting ``*`` imports, e.g. by not importing anything? Are you targeting a specific minimum version, e.g. [Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/)?

Answer (score 2):

You can define what Objects, functions and classes get imported with `import *` from your module with `__all__`

in the beginning of your module add:

`__all__ = []`

Everything you put in that list can be imported with `from yourmodule import *`.
Everything else that is not named can still be accessed with `yourmodule.objectname`.

Example:
Let's assume you have 2 functions in your module.
E.g.:

```
def foo():
    print("Foo")

def bar():
    print("Bar")
```

Importing * from your module will import `foo` and `bar`.

If you add `__all__ = ['foo']` then `import *` will only import `foo`.
And if you add `__all__ = []` then `import *` should not import anything.

Edit:
if you leave the list empty, nothing will be imported, however if you want an error to be raised so that users understand that you don't want to allow import *, then add one entry that will fail, e.g.: `__all__=['NO_WILDCARD_IMPORT_ALLOWED']`.

Comment: although, it should be noted, the error message will be quite confusing.

Comment: True, the error will look like this:
# Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'NO_WILDCARD_IMPORT_ALLOWED'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NO_WILDCARD_IMPORT_ALLOWED' #